# How can the bg-image size be adjusted according to the scale of the image?

Tags: html, css, web, responsive, parallax

I am trying to build a parallax-website but I'm running into problems when it comes to adjusting the size of the image.
My goal is to have the image in the background (obviously) and scroll over it.

To have the second layer in the foreground, I need to specify the height of the "gap" until the second layer starts scrolling over the image. If I understand it correctly, that's the value `min-height: X;` of the `.bg-img1` (etc.) in my code.

Of course I can simply enter a number of pixels, let's say `600`, and always have the distance of `600px`. But what I would like to archieve is that the height is scaling according to scale of the bg-image. Otherwise I will have a tiny image with lots of white space on smaller devices.

Some of my code:

```
.bgimg-1, .bgimg-2, .bgimg-3 {
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0.65;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  -webkit-background-size: 100% auto;
  -moz-background-size: 100% auto;
  -o-background-size: 100% auto;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;


  }
  .bgimg-1 {
    background-image: url("images/viive_10.jpg");
    min-height: 600px;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .bgimg-2 {
    background-image: url("images/viive_26.jpg");
    min-height: 600px;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .bgimg-3 {
    background-image: url("images/viive_24.jpg");
    min-height: 600px;
    width: 100%;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can test width *background-size:cover;* or *background-size:content;* here you have the difference.

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background-size/

Comment: Thank you for your comment!
Unfortunately, it didn't work (neither when I enter it as background size, nor as min-height)... The images are not longer visible.

Comment: If the div is empty you need display:block to get the size

Comment: So I got this in my html-document:
`code`
<div class="bgimg-2">
  <div class="caption">
    <span class="border" style="background-color:transparent;font-size:2em;font-weight:600;color: #f7f7f7;">DR&Auml;GER VIIVE</span>
  </div>
</div>
`code`

Comment: and this in my styles:
`code`
.bgimg-1, .bgimg-2, .bgimg-3 {
  position: relative;
  display:block;
  opacity: 0.65;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  -webkit-background-size: 100% auto;
  -moz-background-size: 100% auto;
  -o-background-size: 100% auto;
  background-size: content;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
   width: 100%;


}
.bgimg-1 {
  background-image: url("images/viive_10.jpg");

}

.bgimg-2 {
  background-image: url("images/viive_26.jpg");

}

.bgimg-3 {
  background-image: url("images/viive_24.jpg");

}
`code`

Comment: but the images still disappear - did I forget something?

Comment: Look it seems your code is correct, here´s the fiddle, only I added display:block http://jsfiddle.net/MAXXALANDER/46s7a2cj/3/

Comment: Seems I forgot write min-height, here you have http://jsfiddle.net/MAXXALANDER/46s7a2cj/9/

Comment: Thank you for the fiddle! I made a fiddle with the rest of the code (in a condensed version): http://jsfiddle.net/xva4fs7j/4/ When I scale down the website, I get white areas at the top and bottom of the parallax-bg-images (as if they were not big enough). Do you know why and if I can fix this somehow? It shouldn't scroll further up and down than the size of the image. I tried so many versions and googled but I just can't find a solution.